How often have unanimous decisions been overturned?
With the recent Loper Bright Enterprises v. Raimondo and Relentless,Inc. v. Department of Commerce decision overturning of the unanimous 1984 decision in Chevron v. Natural Resources Defense Council, I wondered just how often in its history, has the Supreme Court overturned a previous unanimous decision?

I was aware of one other instance:

Valentine v. Chrestensen,
316 U.S. 52 (1942) was overruled by Virginia State Board of Pharmacy v. Virginia Citizens Consumer Council, Inc.,
425 U.S. 748 (1976).

But I direct readers to ohwilleke's more complete list (although still only a sampling).
I also note that even without a dissent, the presence of a concurrence may render the point of law that would eventually be overturned non-unanimous. And judgments with dissents may have had unanimity on the point of law. So unanimity in the opinion may have less significance than you are assuming.

More than 300 U.S. Supreme Court cases have been overruled by later U.S. Supreme Court cases in at least 236 overruling decisions from its inception until 2024 (counting multiple decisions overruling the same case decided on the same day as one case).
There are at least eleven cases where a U.S. Supreme Court decision entered without a dissent (two were not truly unanimous but had no dissents from the judgment) were overruled by a later U.S. Supreme Court decision, including one noted by Jen in her answer. These eleven cases are:

Baker v. Nelson (1971) was overruled by Obergefell v. Hodges, 576 U.S. 644 (2015).

Hoyt v. Florida, 368 U.S. 57 (1961) was overruled by Taylor v. Louisiana, 419 U.S. 522 (1975).

Breedlove v. Suttles, 302 U.S. 277 (1937) was overruled by Harper v. Virginia State Board of Elections, 383 U.S. 663 (1966).

Pace v. Alabama, 106 U.S. 583 (1883) was overruled by McLaughlin v. Florida, 379 U.S. 184 (1964).

Agins v. City of Tiburon, 447 U.S. 255 (1980) was overruled by Lingle v. Chevron U.S.A. Inc., 544 U.S. 528 (2005).

Ex parte Bain, 121 U.S. 1 (1887) was overruled by United States v. Miller, 471 U.S. 130 (1985).

Abood v. Detroit Board of Education, 431 U.S. 209 (1977) (not truly unanimous, but with no dissenting opinions) was overruled by Janus v. AFSCME, 585 U.S. (2018).

Valentine v. Chrestensen, 316 U.S. 52 (1942) was overruled by Virginia State Pharmacy Board v. Virginia Citizens Consumer Council, 425 U.S. 748 (1976) (also listed by Jen).

Whitney v. California, 274 U.S. 357 (1927) (not truly unanimous, but with no dissenting opinions) was overruled by Brandenburg v. Ohio, 395 U.S. 444 (1969).

Paul v. Virginia, 75 U.S. (8 Wall.) 168 (1869) was overruled by United States v. South-Eastern Underwriters Ass'n, 322 U.S. 533 (1944).

Chevron v. Natural Resources Defense Council (1984) (a 6-0 case in which three judges did not participate in the decision) was overruled by Loper Bright Enterprises v. Raimondo (2024) and Relentless,Inc. v. Department of Commerce (2024).


This does not purport to be a comprehensive and complete list. Only a portion of the overruled cases (a bit more than half of them, in a selection of cases that was biased towards higher profile cases that were more likely to draw dissents when decided originally) were reviewed in connection with the preparation of this answer.
It is also worth noting that in at least as many cases, if not more, only a single judge dissented (sometimes with only a partial dissent).See, e.g., Swift v. Tyson, 41 U.S. (16 Pet.) 1 (1842) (with only a partial dissent from a single justice), which was overruled by Erie Railroad Co. v. Tompkins, 304 U.S. 64 (1938).
In many of those cases, John Marshall Harlan, who served on the U.S. Supreme Court from 1877 to 1911 (not to be confused with his grandson of the same name who served on the U.S. Supreme Court from 1955 to 1971), was the sole dissenter in the decision that was later overruled. He was also the lead dissenter in many more cases. According to the Wikipedia link to his biography above:

He is often called "The Great Dissenter" due to his many dissents in
cases that restricted civil liberties, including the Civil Rights
Cases, Plessy v. Ferguson, and Giles v. Harris. Many of Harlan's views
expressed in his notable dissents would become the official view of
the Supreme Court starting from the 1950s Warren Court and onward.

This list does not include decisions that have been abrogated by a subsequent constitutional amendment or by subsequent amended statutes.
